# How to convert C++ project to iOS embedded framework

Tags: c++, ios, cmake, frameworks, dylib

Consider I have a simple C++ project that does some math operations. The requirement is to integrate the C++ module as a dynamic library on both our iOS and Android apps.

Calculator.hpp

```
#ifndef Calculator_H
#define Calculator_H
#if defined __cplusplus

class Calculator
{
public:
    float add(float a, float b);
    float subtract(float a, float b);
    float multiply(float a, float b);
    float divide(float a, float b);
};

#endif
#endif
```

Calculator.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "Calculator.hpp"

float Calculator::add(float a, float b) {
    return a+b;
}

float Calculator::subtract(float a, float b) {
    return a-b;
}

float Calculator::multiply(float a, float b) {
    return a*b;
}

float Calculator::divide(float a, float b) {
    return a/b;
}
```

In Android it was pretty simple and straightforward. Using `CMake`, the library was cross compiled to create a `.so` file and the same was integrated with header in the app.

When coming to iOS, I am able to access the resources in 2 ways

1. I am able to use the CPP module as source files. Creating an Objective C++ wrapper, I am able to access the CPP sources.
2. Using `CMake`, I am able to create a Xcode project and use it in the iOS app along with the header file and Objective C++ wrapper.

Using `CMake`, I am able to generate the `.dylib` file, but, unlike Android, it is not possible to integrate the `.dylib` file directly in the app. Some suggest to embed the `.dylib` file in a framework and use it in the app. But, there is no proper document or sources available on internet.

What is the proper way to integrate dynamic library (of a C++ module) in an iOS app? May be consider using the provided C++ code.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/FRAMEWORK.html

Comment: Frameworks are just dylibs with a specific path pattern. You can simply rename your dylib to `SomeName.framework/SomeName` and edit its load commands with `install_name_tool` (don't forget to re-sign afterwards).

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)